# how to package a custom Jar task with JIB?

Tags: java, docker, gradle, jib

I'm using [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin) to Containerize the output of some Gradle Jar tasks. This works fine for default Jar task. My issue is we have a custom Jar task hooked into our build process e.g.

```
tasks.register('myOtherJarTask',jar){
   //do stuff, triggered by assemble task
   // outputted to non default directory
}
```

and I want the output of this to be containerized not the default Jar, The default Jar is also still valid for us for other reasons. Is there a way to allow for this in JIB, from looking at the source code of the JIB plugin it seems it coded to expect the [output of the Jar task](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/jib/gradle/GradleProjectProperties.java#L272). Code from Jib plugin:

```
      Jar jarTask = (Jar) project.getTasks().findByName("jar");
      Path jarPath = jarTask.getArchiveFile().get().getAsFile().toPath();
      log(LogEvent.debug("Using JAR: " + jarPath));
      javaContainerBuilder.addToClasspath(jarPath);
```

I also tried Copying the jar from 'myOtherJarTask' into the container using extraDirectories property and executing that way via a entrypoint but the default Jar does not contain a main class so that blocks this (myOtherJarTask has a main class). restructuring the project so the defaut Jar produces my desired output is not a option.

Maybe there is another way that is not clear to me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How about changing the behavior of the default Jar task using property (variable)? When the property is not specified via `-P`, then do normal Jar task. If the property is specified, do "myOtherJarTask" in the Jar task.

Answer (score 0):

Just another thought: Have you tried adding your custom jar to the runtime classpath with [`jib.container.extraClasspath`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#extended-usage)?